# Beginning installation trouble

Tags: system-installation

I'm trying to install Wubi 12.10 for my Windows 7 64-bit computer. I am able to save the executable, and once I do so the window asking for my permission to continue pops up. I press 'Continue' and then nothing happens. Why isn't the installation process proceeding as described?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you dualboot Ubuntu with Windows. WUBI is a very bad way of installing Ubuntu and eventually, you may find many things not working. How to install ubuntu alongside Windows you may find here http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-desktop-latest